# Spring OAuth2 - How to configure authentication service that it should pass User credential via request header or body

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have an app that is implemented using spring security oauth2 version 2.0 So if user needs access Token. He need to send the user credentials as query params:

```
/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=website-CLIENT&username=test1&password=test1
```

Please can any one help me what configuration should be done so user credentials can go as request body or request header.

Spring Configuration File:

```
 <!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="client"/>
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="customAuthenticationManager"
      class="com.xyz.authentication.XYZDBAuthenticationProvider"/>

<!-- Authentication in config file -->
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationManager"/>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>

<!-- Token Store  -->
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTokenStore" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTokenStore"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="#{systemProperties['JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING']}/#{systemProperties['DATABASE']}?autoReconnect=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="#{systemProperties['USER_NAME']}"/>
    <property name="password" value="#{systemProperties['PASSWORD']}"/>
</bean>


<bean id="tokenServices" class="xyz.oauth2.CustomTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
    <!-- VIV -->
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="7776000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
</bean>
<!-- Token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                            user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:implicit/>
    <oauth:refresh-token/>
    <oauth:client-credentials/>
    <oauth:password/>
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                       token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>


<!-- Client Definition -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

    <oauth:client client-id="mobile-CLIENT"
                  authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token,implicit"
                  authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT"
                  scope="read,write,trust"
                  access-token-validity="7776000"
                  refresh-token-validity="15552000"/>

    <oauth:client client-id="website-CLIENT"
                  authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token,implicit"
                  authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT"
                  scope="read,write,trust"
                  access-token-validity="7776000"
                  refresh-token-validity="15552000"/>

</oauth:client-details-service>

    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
</sec:global-method-security>
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>
```

Comment: Please help anybody :'( My deadline is near :'(

Comment: at least guide me

Comment: content type:  x-www-url-encoded with POST request is the only way to go.